# How to give rspec fake Time.now value

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to write an rspec test. This is my code.

```
# mylogger.rb
class MyLogger
  def save
    File.open("#{Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H')}.log","w"){|f| f.puts "log" }
  end
end

# mylogger_spec.rb
require 'mylogger'

describe MyLogger, "#save" do
  it "saves a log file" do
    logger = MyLogger.new
    logger.save
    # check whether proper file has been written.
  end
end
```

How can I set a fake `Time.now` value, and write a test for this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would extract the file name creation and test it separately. Something like:

```
# mylogger.rb
class MyLogger
  def save
    File.open(filename, "w") { |f| f.puts "log" }
  end

  def filename(time = Time.now)
    "#{time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H')}.log"
  end
end

# mylogger_spec.rb
require 'mylogger'

describe MyLogger do
  describe "#save" do
    it "saves a log file" do
      logger = MyLogger.new
      logger.stub(:filename) { "test.log" }
      logger.save
      # check whether "test.log" has been written.
    end
  end

  describe "#filename" do
    it "creates a nice filename" do
      logger = MyLogger.new
      time = Time.new(2002, 10, 31, 2)
      logger.filename(time).should == "2002103102.log"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a gem like Timecop (see: https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop)